# WordPress How to access global from function.php in javascript

Tags: wordpress

I added a global variable in functions.php which is in my theme folder but its not resolving in javascript

So in functions.php I have:

```
global $the_url;
$the_url =  "https://google.com";
```

Then in my main.js file I added:

```
alert ('<?php echo $the_url ; ?>');
```

but my alert actually outputs the string `<?php echo $the_url; ?>`

I've also tried alert `('<?php print($the_url); ?>');` but again I get the string in the alert

Finally I tried removing the quotes thus `alert (<?php echo $requests_url ; ?>);` but I get an error of unexpected token <

Anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use wp_localize_script**

```
<?php

// Register the script first.
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Now we can localize the script with our data.
$translation_array = array( 'some_string' => 'some value', 'a_value' => '10' );
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// The script can be enqueued now or later.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

**You can access the variables in JavaScript as follows:**

```
<script>
    alert( object_name.some_string) ; // alerts 'Some value'
</script>
```

**Above code is excerpt from [Wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)**

Comment: This was correct just not easy to figure out how to use it. In case helps others, I did the following: I only used wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script but NOT wp_register_script. In wp_enqueue_script was confused about why I needed a path. Apparently just something you make up and will be generated there. Also, only worked if I put all this in scripts.php, probly because I'm using roots starter theme. I added it inside the function which enqueues all scripts and then calls add_action. For me that function was called roots_scripts. Now in my main.js the variables are automatically visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using PHP code in a JS file. You need to move the JS code to a PHP file such as header.php before the line `</head>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('<?php echo $the_url ; ?>');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code

Example in functions.php

```
<?php function my_code() { >
<script>

var home = '<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>';

alert(home);

</script>
<?php } 
add_action('wp_head','my_code');
?>
```